# Document editing/rendering library on Android?

Tags: android, library

I'm looking for an Android library/UI control that can **render** a document (preferably OpenXML, but I'm open to RTF and lesser formats) **and allow basic editing**: deleting and typing. Formatting isn't really a concern. Cross-platform with iOS is an added bonus.

Free is always nice (even with draconian licensing), but I am open to reasonably priced solutions. [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/word-component-suite.aspx) for $1000, is not reasonable for what I need (basic editing of one format).

The use case for this is that I'm generating a document, and the user might sometimes want to do some sanitizing, like entering line breaks to push a block of text onto the next page.

Required elements:

- lists
- bold
- italic
- underlined

So far, the best I've come across is to use RTF and extend [EditTExt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), but it does not handle lists. I've heard of the Google Drive Realtime API, but it isn't obvious (to me, at least) whether or not they provide an editor that I can embed.

Comment: What specifically do you need that the `EditText` widget does not offer? You can convert between HTML and `Spanned` objects that can be edited by an `EditText`, and HTML is a more popular document format.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's a good question, maybe plain old HTML is good enough. I'd like to actually use already written documents, insert auto-generated content, and then allow for manual sanitizing. In my experience though, conversion to HTML has been terrible, so I'll see. Thank you!

Comment: @CommonsWare Right, now I see why everyone says EditText is useless. It's only capable of editing a (very) small subset of HTML. This doesn't fit my requirements at all.

Comment: Feel free to explain *what specifically* is missing that your "requirements" call for. After all, any software recommendation will need to take that into account.

Comment: @CommonsWare specifically: I need to be able to at least render lists, bold, italic, and underlined text - i.e. a basic document.

Comment: That is not specific. You clearly have a vision of what "basic richly formatted documents" means to you. If you don't explain the roster of features that you seek, how do you expect anyone to recommend something that has those features? Besides, EditText is capable of more than what you cited.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm sorry but I don't know how much more specific I can go than those four items? EditText isn't capable of handling HTML, just a subset of it, and that subset does not include lists. I'm aware that it can be extended, but I'm looking for something pre-built. I am capable of explaining thank you, and I don't understand the hostility.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread your previous comment on my phone. `EditText` can handle "lists, bold, italic, and underlined text" (see `BulletSpan` and `StyleSpan`), though you need to supply your own toolbar for user-level control over the formatting. Or, you can use a `WebView` and try the various HTML rich editors available for Web sites.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of office apps for android:

- [andropenoffice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andropenoffice)
- [Polaris Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infraware.office.link)

**References**

- [Source Code - AndrOpen Office - OpenOffice for Android](https://sites.google.com/site/andropenoffice/source-code)
- [The Best Office Suite for Android](https://lifehacker.com/5868343/the-best-office-suite-for-android)
- [10 best office apps for Android - Android Authority](https://www.androidauthority.com/best-office-apps-for-android-281250/)
- [10 best office apps for Android | TechRadar](https://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/10-best-office-apps-for-android-993343)